# Add active menu on DIVI Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, divi

I am trying to add an active Menu when clicked on the bottom menu, visible only on mobile and tablets.

I tried different code snippets but it seems that I am went to the rabbit hole with no luck.

[This](https://enginljon.is/) is the link. On the desktop, it's hidden so you'll need to go on mobile via inspect.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**I also tried this code** following the tutorial [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-toggle-divi-transform-properties-on-click-with-jquery), changing the classes names ofc.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery('.transform_target').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('toggle-transform-animation');
    });  
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function ds_setup_collapsible_submenus() {
        var $menu = $('.et_mobile_menu'),
        top_level_link = '.et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a';
        
        $menu.find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).off('click');
            if ( $(this).is(top_level_link) ) {
                $(this).attr('href', '#');
            }

            if ( ! $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').length ) {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    $(this).parents('.mobile_nav').trigger('click');
                });
            } 
            else {
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().toggleClass('visible');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        ds_setup_collapsible_submenus();
    }, 700);
 });
</script>
```

```css
.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a,
#main-header .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a:after, #main-header .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
    font-family: 'ETmodules';
    text-align: center;
    speak: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 18px;
    content: '\4c';
    top: 11px;
    right: 13px;
}

.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children.visible > a:after,
#main-header .et_mobile_menu .menu-item-has-children.visible > a:after {
    content: '\4d';
}

.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu ul.sub-menu,
#main-header .et_mobile_menu ul.sub-menu,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu li.visible > ul.sub-menu,
#main-header .et_mobile_menu li.visible > ul.sub-menu,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l #main-header .et_mobile_menu li.visible > ul.sub-menu,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_fullwidth_menu .et_mobile_menu li.visible > ul.sub-menu,
.et-db #et-boc .et-l .et_pb_menu .et_mobile_menu li.visible > ul.sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: when i add jquery it wont save the code...

Comment: You can use header.php or footer.php...